# workflow pause until x - queued?

Tags: workflow, designer-workflow, sharepoint-designer

If I use a workflow which starts on change but I also add a pause until 12PM then this workflow will be "queued" right?
But what happens if I change something again? Will the workflow start a second time?

For exmaple: 8AM Task1 is changed. -> workflow starts and send email to owner but pauses until 12PM.
10AM Task1 is changed again -> workflow starts and send email to owner but pauses until 12PM.
and so on.

That means the owner will get 2 emails right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats right - 2 x changes = 2 x workflow instances.

You can trap for the change by examining some data in the list item like a hidden column that the workflow updates or just look at the version number if you want to control how many times the wf email gets sent.

If this is just an "item has been edited" type wf, then the built in alerts system can send a daily digest of the changes rather than needing a specific workflow creating.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, new workflow kicks off every time we change an item in the list but the existing workflows from previous edits don't stop. Finally we'll get a bunch of emails.